# Stream media to Airplay (AppleTv) from Cordova Android App

Tags: android, cordova, airplay

I am currently developing an Android app using the **Cordova 3.5** framework. The app allows users to watch a few videos, and I would like to be able to stream those videos from the **Android** app to an **Apple TV** or any **Airplay**-compatible client.

Is it possible to do this using Cordova for Android ? I did some research and found pretty much nothing on the subject.

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you have any answer to this?